# Undefined on getting data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting data from a JSON file, but got this output (which I copied from inspect element - edit as HTML)

```
<li>
    <a href="function" link()="" {="" [native="" code]="" }="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">undefined</a>
</li>
```

The script that I am using is

```
(function($) {
    var url = 'http://divakarparashar.hol.es/innovation/mobile/protected/json/news.json';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: true,
        jsonpCallback: 'MyJSONPCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json){
            $.each(json, function(i, j) {
                $("#links").append("<li><a href=" + j.link + " class='ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r'>" + j.text + "</li>");
                console.log(j.link + j.text);
                //used console.log to just run a check, same output there too
            });
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Output in console.log

> function link() { [native code] }undefined

I have also tried using file from local server as I am running this file on localhost, but it gives the same output.

Comment: Also, If you add `console.log(json);` before each you will see that json is only the first object. The link method belongs to the string prototype (to convert strings to anchors) which is why you are seeing native function first.

Comment: The error is because your JSONP is not correctly formatted, the objects need to be surrounded by `[]`, eg: `MyJSONPCallback([{
    "link":"#",
    "text":"This is news 1"
}, ... ]);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 
Thanks. Everything is working as expected after
          MyJSONPCallback([{ "link":"#", "text":"This is news 1" }, ... ])

Hope there is no need to use " ; " after }])

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I added it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your JSONP is not correctly formatted, the objects need to be surrounded by `[]`, for example:

```
MyJSONPCallback([
    { 
        "link":"#", 
        "text":"This is news 1" 
    }, 
    // other objects... 
])
```

Answer (score 1):

I hit the URL you are accessing and notice that it is not being served as json format... Within PHP, my JSON data is served using the following:

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

You need to do something similar server side, or else you need to request txt or javascript and not json with your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Are you okay with the JSON returned by [your url](http://divakarparashar.hol.es/innovation/mobile/protected/json/news.json) ??

Because i have this :

```
MyJSONPCallback({ "link":"#", "text":"This is news 1" }, { "link":"#", "text":"This is news 2" }, { "link":"#", "text":"This is news 3" })
```

And it's not a valid JSON and not an array. This must be return something like :

```
[{ "link":"#", "text":"This is news 1" }, { "link":"#", "text":"This is news 2" }, { "link":"#", "text":"This is news 3" }]
```